# Change url address in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect this address:

```
mysite.com/reports/flight?pay=888&invoice=321
```

to this one:

```
mysite.com/reports/#!/flight?pay=888&invoice=321
```

How can I do it?